# Being notified when a view model property changes the checkbox value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a checkbox bound to a property in my view model. When I tick the checkbox the view model property changes, when I change the view model property the checkbox ticks.

What I'm trying to do is being notified when the checkbox value changes (triggered by the view model change). If I tick the checkbox I can catch the 'change' event, but when I change the view model the event doesn't fire.

I need to be able to be notified about this change because the script I use to skin the checkboxes relies on this event.

I looked at custom bindings as a way to get around this but I was hoping there was a built in solution.

**I'm using knockout 1.7.**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be notified of when the user ticks the checkbox and when the view model property changes programmatically, you can use [Knockout's .subscribe function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) on the observable value:

```
var viewModel = {
   isChecked: ko.observable(false)
};

viewModel.isChecked.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: In order for this to work I need to have access to the observable in my skin script :\.

Comment: Do you have access to the DOM? If so, you can use ko.dataFor(domElement) to get the observable.

Comment: @Megacan did this solve your problem? If so, please mark as the answer. If not, please let us know what part is still missing.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did solve the problem by rewriting the script that handles the UI. But I did use your suggestions in the. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and glad I could help.